Pass system env variable to self-hosted github-runner
I have a self-hosted runner based on Mac OS Ventura 13.6.5.
Mac has installed Python using Homebrew:
brew install python

and Path for python variable in .zshrc
export PATH="$(brew --prefix python)/libexec/bin:$PATH"

In the workflow, I have a bash script that use Python to do some work, however, when I start flow it threw an error that python is not found
I have tried to install Python setup GitHub action, however, step just are stucking for an unknown reason
- uses: actions/setup-python@v5
  with:
    python-version: '3.10' 

Also I tried to add a Path variable to the runners .env file, but without any effect
python="$(brew --prefix)/opt/python@3/libexec/bin

How can I tell Github runner to use the python variable from the system variables?

Did you install the python before you installed the runner or after?

Python was installed after the runner
